# I can't migrate azure storage standard to premium

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need migrate azure blob storage from standard to premium

I try exec

```
azcopy.exe copy [source with SAS] [destination with SAS] --recursive
```

and return this error:

```
RESPONSE Status: 404 The specified blob does not exist.
   Content-Length: [216]
   Content-Type: [application/xml]
   Date: [Tue, 08 Oct 2019 16:34:11 GMT]
   Server: [Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0]
   X-Ms-Error-Code: [BlobNotFound]
   X-Ms-Request-Id: [5f5b409d-d01c-000e-1df6-7d67ae000000]
   X-Ms-Version: [2018-11-09]
```

Then, I try

```
azcopy.exe copy [source with SAS] [destination with SAS] --blob-type PageBlob --recursive
```

And all files filed because:

```
Content-Length: [0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
User-Agent: [AzCopy/10.2.1 Azure-Storage/0.7 (go1.12; Windows_NT)]                                                                                                                                                                           
X-Ms-Blob-Cache-Control: []                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
X-Ms-Blob-Content-Disposition: []                                                                                                                                                                                                            
X-Ms-Blob-Content-Encoding: []                                                                                                                                                                                                               
X-Ms-Blob-Content-Language: []                                                                                                                                                                                                               
X-Ms-Blob-Content-Length: [777475]                                                                                                                                                                                                           
X-Ms-Blob-Content-Type: [image/jpeg]                                                                                                                                                                                                         
X-Ms-Blob-Sequence-Number: [0]                                                                                                                                                                                                               
X-Ms-Blob-Type: [PageBlob]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
X-Ms-Client-Request-Id: [...]                                                                                                                                                                               
X-Ms-Version: [2018-03-28]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             
RESPONSE Status: 400 The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.                                                                                                                                                     
Content-Length: [337]                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Content-Type: [application/xml]                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Date: [Tue, 08 Oct 2019 16:29:51 GMT]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Server: [Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0]                                                                                                                                                                                       
X-Ms-Error-Code: [InvalidHeaderValue]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
X-Ms-Request-Id: [...]                                                                                                                                                                                      
X-Ms-Version: [2018-03-28]
```

How can I tranform my blockblobs to pageblobs?

Thank you

Comment: If you try with a recent version and see the note here, about not preserving the blob tier, it should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs#copy-blobs-between-storage-accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, the issue was caused by your block blob size in the source container is not a multiple of `512` bytes.

Actually, when running the Azcopy command, the `INFO` has mentioned that.

[image]

So if you want to do that, the block blob size must be a multiple of `512` bytes.  I test the command the files which are multiple of `512` bytes, it works fine.

[image]

My source container:

[image]

My destination container:

[image]

Comment: yes, but, how can i change the size? Do you know a tool for this?

Comment: @DaniGSd I am not sure, I think this is your responsibility, I can just tell you the usage of it. I just use `fsutil file createnew test123.txt 512` in cmd to create the files to test. And you should know, even if you download the block blob in local, then you upoload them as pageblob, they also need to meet the 512 requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tranform my blockblobs to pageblobs?

It is not possible to copy a block blob as page blob. During copy operation, blob type is preserved and can't be changed.

What you would need to do is download the block blob from source account and then upload it into target account as page blob.

Comment: how can I change the type before i upload it?

Comment: At the time of uploading the file, you can specify the type of the blob. However I don’t think that’ll solve your problem as page blob size must be a multiple of 512 bytes. Can you confirm that the size of the file meets that criteria?

Comment: You can change the blob type, when copying blobs, just by setting the --blob-type parameter